# Fixed sidebar on scroll then back to normal when scrolled up

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to mimic this effect for sidebar:
https://www.matchesfashion.com/us/womens/just-in/just-in-this-month

I think I have everything working expect the scroll up functionality. Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vVByvR?editors=0010

```
    var $sideBar = $('.sidebar');
    var sideBarOriginalST = $sideBar.position().top;
    var placedAchieved = false;
    var sideBarPostion = -570;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var stopPos = ($sideBar.position().top + $sideBar.outerHeight())  - 291;

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var sT = $(this).scrollTop();
        $sideBar = $('.sidebar');

        if(sideBarOriginalST <=  sT && !placedAchieved) {
            $sideBar.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: (sT-sideBarOriginalST) * -1
            });

            placedAchieved = false;
        }

        if(stopPos <= sT) {
            placedAchieved = true;

            $sideBar.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: sideBarPostion
            })
        }

        // having trouble on scroll up event
        if (sT < lastScrollTop) {
            console.log(sT, sideBarPostion);
            placedAchieved = false;
            // $sideBar.css({
            //     position: 'fixed',
            //     top:  sideBarPostion+=1
            // });
        }

        if(sideBarOriginalST >= sT) {
            $sideBar.css({
                position: 'static',
                top: 0
            });
            placedAchieved = false;
        }

        lastScrollTop = sT;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
var $sidebar = $('.sidebar');
var sidebar_height = $sidebar.height();
var $last_item = $('.sidebar .row:last-child');
var last_item_offset = $last_item.offset().top;
var last_item_height = $last_item.height();

 $(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();

   if(scroll_top >= last_item_offset)
   {
     $sidebar.css({
       position: 'fixed',
       top: '-' + (sidebar_height - last_item_height) + 'px'
     });
   }
   else
   {
     $sidebar.css({
       position: 'static',
       top: 'auto'
     });
   }
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oavZyg?editors=0010

Comment: No not exactly, I have already achieved this effect. If you look at the example link I attached, it shows how the sidebar becomes sticky but if you scroll all the way down then back up, you can still scroll up in the sidebar but then becomes sticky again once you hit the top of the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

No need for javascript! Use `position: sticky`.
More info: https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Comment: No, not what i am looking for. Does not achieve the same effect.